# Django admin proxy model edit form, prefilter on the form level only

Tags: python, django

I made a proxy model for these two models :

```
Class Student(models.Model):
   name:
   is_special :
   foo_n :
   assigned_teacher (foreign_key to Teacher model) :
```

and :

```
Class Teacher(models.Model):
   name:
   has_certification :
   foo_n :
```

I made a proxy model to manage the students because one of my user only needs a list with a few fields to magage special students.

```
 Class ManageSpecialStudent(Student):
      class Meta:
         proxy = True
```

The idea is to have a list of all the special students and a list of all the teachers that have a certification.

Then in my admin.py I made an admin class for that proxy model

```
class ManageSpecialStudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ('name','foo','assigned_teacher','is_special',...)
       fields = ('name','foo','assigned_teacher',...)
```

But I want to filter the available assigned_teacher depending on a value on the teacher model. If the teacher has the certification to teach to a special kid, show him in the list of the admin form of that proxy model.

What I did is

```
 def get_queryset(self, request):
          return self.model.objects.filter(assigned_teacher__has_certification=True, is_special=True)
```

And it kinda of works, the problem is that query affects also the list_display. All the students who don't have a teacher assigned are filtered out, and I don't want this.

Is there a way just to apply the filter to assigned_teacher only on the form(fields) of that proxy ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it with the following code :

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return self.model.objects.filter(is_special=True,)

def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
     context['adminform'].form.fields['assigned_teacher'].queryset = Teacher.objects.filter(has_certification=True)
     return super(ManageSpecialStudent, self).render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: wrong voted... cannot reproduce. Don't know which version of Django is. Sorry

Comment: @fero it was 1.6.x at the time and as of today this code run on 1.8.x and still works

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution at the admin level, rather than modifying the models (when you have proxy admin models, not proxy models) is to do the following:

```
class ManageSpecialStudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','foo','assigned_teacher','is_special',...)
    fields = ('name','foo','assigned_teacher',...)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(assigned_teacher__has_certification=True, is_special=True)
```

For more information about using django admin as above please check out [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset).